# Create all the '' small'' matrix from a bigger one - Haskell

Tags: haskell, matrix

I have a rectangular matrix with cases containing B or N. An example of matrix:

```
g0 = [[B,B,B,B,B,B,N],
      [B,B,N,B,N,B,B],
      [N,B,N,N,N,N,N],
      [B,B,B,N,N,B,N],
      [N,N,N,B,B,B,B],
      [B,B,B,N,N,B,N]]
```

I have a type rectangle like `[Int,Int,Int,Int]` and a function that gets a smaller rectangular matrix from my matrix with this type. Here's the function but that's not the most important part:

```
getRectangle :: Rectangle -> Grille -> Grille -- cette fonction récupère la grille qui correspond au rectangle donné
getRectangle (i,j,l,c) g = transpose (getLigne (j,c,(nbLigne (transpose g0))) (transpose (getLigne (i,l,(nbLigne g0)) g0)))
--transpose get create a matrix with (n,m) = (lines,columns) in a matrix (m,n) and nbLigne return the number of lines (or columns when used with transpose) of a matrix.

getLigne :: (Int,Int,Int) -> Grille -> Grille 
getLigne (i,l,0) g = []                     
getLigne (1,l,1) g = [head g]                
getLigne (i,l,indice) [] = []
getLigne (i,l,indice) g         
    | indice == (i+l) =  getLigne (i,l,(indice-1)) (init g) ++ [last g]
    | indice == i = [last g]
    | i < indice && indice < (i+l) = getLigne (i,l,(indice-1)) (init g) ++ [last g]
    | otherwise = getLigne (i,l,(indice-1)) (init g)
```

Here's an example:

```
*Main> affiche (getRectangle (1,2,2,3) g0)
[B,B,B,B]
[B,N,B,N]
[B,N,N,N]
```

So, I have a tuple with `(i,j,l,c)`. Knowing that `1<=i<i+l<=n` and `1<=j<j+c<=m` with n the number of lines of the matrix and m the number of columns.
To be clear, with a tuple `(i,j,l,c)`, my function create a rectangle, from my matrix, formed with these cases: `(i,j)`, `(i+l,j)`, `(i,j+c)` and `(i+l,j+c)`.

Now that I can create a single rectangle, I need to create all the possibles rectangles in any matrix. I don't have any clue on how I can do this since I feel like there is so many rectangles in a single matrix and cover all the cases seems very hard and long to me.

Maybe that I wasn't clear on some points, feel free to ask.

Comment: This looks as a job for list comprehensions: enumerate all possible rectangles. You already know which constraints these 4-tuples must satisfy, so you can exploit them.

Comment: Indeed list comprehensions may do the job but I can't see how to cover all the issues. I have 4 conditions so it seems hard to cover them all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salut :),

For combinations, I often work with the list monad.
Note that using the `do` notation like this is equivalent to working with list comprehensions

From a position you can deduce all the rectangles that can originate from a given point:

```
allRectsOriginatingFrom :: Point -> Grille -> [Rectangle]
allRectsOriginatingFrom (x, y) g
    -- Si le point est dans ta grille...
    | (x >= 1 && x <= width g) && (y >= 1 && y <= height g) = do
        w <- [0 .. width g - x]
        h <- [0 .. height g - y]
        return (x, y, w, h)
    -- Sinon y'a pas de rectangle possible
    | otherwise = []
```

From there, your just have to map the function over all the possible positions on your grid:

```
allPointsOf :: Grille -> [Point]
allPointsOf g = do
    x <- [1 .. width g]
    y <- [1 .. height g]
    return (x, y)

allRectsOf :: Grille -> [Rectangle]
allRectsOf g = do
    pos <- allPointsOf g
    allRectsOriginatingFrom pos g
```

And finally, mapping it with your `getLigne` function will get you every rectangle in your grid.

PS: Try to create datatypes instead of type aliases, it's better in my opinion (e.g. create a datatype like `data Rectangle = Rectangle Int Int Int Int` instead of `type Rectangle = (Int, Int, Int, Int)`).

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I needed. So, I just have to map it with `getRectangle` but how can I bind an argument with map? Explanation: I got: `allGridOf :: [Rectangle] -> [Grille]
allGridOf x = map getRectangle g0` but it doesn't work. I want to bind g0 here.

Comment: Just use lambda function (or partial application if you can)
`getAllSubGrids g = map (\ r -> getRectangle r g) (allRectsOf g)`

And then use `getAllSubGrids g0`